# Assigning a mysql field value to a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to assign the value of the my below database field (sname) to a php variable (name).but I am getting below error.Can someone help

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or   T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/a4363282/public_html/pune/upload/upload_file.php on line 6

include './connection.php';
$query = "select * from shops WHERE city='pune' AND Ref=1;
$row = mysql_query($query);
$name=$row['sname'];
echo $name;
```

Comment: The error is causing by a missing closing `"` in `$query = "select * from shops WHERE city='pune' AND Ref=1;` which should read as `$query = "select * from shops WHERE city='pune' AND Ref=1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update you're code to MySQLi or PDO.

```
<?php
include './connection.php';
$query = "select * from shops WHERE city='pune' AND Ref=1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo $row['sname'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **double quote** at the **end of query**, **Update this**,

```
include './connection.php';
$query = "select * from shops WHERE city='pune' AND Ref=1";
$row = mysql_query($query);
$name=$row['sname'];
echo $name;
```

Comment: minus voter be aware explain reason?

Comment: i have balanced the vote score because the error in question is relates to syntax error which you have defined ,don't know why people dv without leaving a comment

Comment: @user1153551 Just run your code, then you'll know the reason for the minus.

Comment: thanks everyone.Apologies I missed the double quote here.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using mysql_* statements. Change your code with -

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE city=? AND Ref=?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("si", 'pune', 1);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);

    $array = array();
    while ($fetch = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $array[] = $fetch;
    }
    print_r($array);

    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do with this code because it's wrong

Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource

```
$row = mysql_query($query);
```

here the $row is resource 
so, One of the mysql result functions must be used. so your code would be

```
include './connection.php';
$query = "select * from shops WHERE city='pune' AND Ref='1'";
$row = mysql_query($query);

 while($ansArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)){

   echo $name = $ansArray['sname'];
 }
```